# How to search a dictionary and append a field to JSON by key value?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to write a script like this in Python:

Let's say I have two JSON files, one has a data structure like this :

fruitswithprice.json

```json
 {
  fruit: "banana",
  color: "yellow",
  price : 20,
 }
```

the other is fruitsnoprice.json

```json
  {
  fruit: "banana",
 color: "yellow",
  }
```

I want to append the price field to fruitsnoprice.json for every entry that the key "fruit" matches.

I tried this :

```py
new_dict = []


def add_price(json_file):
    with open("../../dictionary/original.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as original_dictionary, open(json_file, "r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as word_list:
                dictionary = json.load(original_dictionary)
                list_to_append = json.load(word_list)
                              
                for word in dictionary:
                    for wInList in list_to_append:
                        if word['fruit'] == wInList['fruit']:
                            wInList['price'] == word['price']
                            new_dict.append(wInList)
                print(new_dict)
```

getting an error at wInList['price'] == word['price'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this: `wInList['price'] == word['price']`.

You can assign it like this:

```
wInList['price'] = word['price'] # Notice! Just one '='
```